# Binary Tree Upside Down

Tags: swift, binary, binary-search-tree

The output from my code return an empty array while trying to put a binary tree upside down using dfs recursion. How do I fix this ?

```
public class TreeNode {
    var val :Int
    var left: TreeNode?
    var right: TreeNode?
    
        public init(_ val: Int, _ left: TreeNode?, _ right: TreeNode?) {
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
      }

      func upsideDownBinaryTree(_ root: TreeNode?) -> TreeNode? {
        return dfs(current: root)
    }
    
    func dfs( current: TreeNode?) -> TreeNode? {
        if current == nil {
            return nil
        }
        let newRoot = dfs(current: current?.left)
        current?.left?.left = current?.right
        current?.left?.right = current
        current?.left = nil
        current?.right = nil
        return newRoot
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdP3r.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the base case of recursion: it will *always* return `nil`. Since any other returned value is exactly the same as what was retrieved from the recursive call (`newRoot`), it can never be anything else than `nil`. There is no way the function can return anything else than `nil`.

Realise that the case `current == nil` is only there to deal with an empty tree. In all other cases the recursion should stop one step earlier: when it is a node without left child. In that case that node should be returned.

So change:

```
if current == nil {
    return nil
}
```

To:

```
if current?.left == nil {
    return current
}
```

Now the base case is focussed on the non-presence of the left child, and in that case the node itself will be returned. The case where `current` itself is nil is only relevant when the tree is empty, but it is also covered here.